# loadURI() and # FF addon

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox addon for faster searching. I'm using loadURI to load the URLs. What I encountered is that sometimes Firefox wouldn't load the newest request.

Example:

```
getWebNavigation().loadURI("http://www.google.com/", (nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_IS_LINK), null, null, null);

getWebNavigation().loadURI("http://www.google.com/#5555", (nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_IS_LINK), null, null, null);
```

If you execute it, it will load http://www.google.com/#5555 first; and on all other requests it will load google.com.

nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_IS_LINK is required for Google to not reload images and javascript. Bypassing cache works but it has the problem that page is always renewed.

I'm looking for a way to give the latest request priority, while simultaneously not reloading images & javascript.

Before you answer, the following flags do not resolve the problem:

```
LOAD_FLAGS_STOP_CONTENT (STOP_NETWORK, STOP_CONTENT, STOP_ALL),...
LOAD_FLAGS_FIRST_LOAD
```

Answer (score 0):

The original loadURI of http://www.google.com/ starts attempting to load. However your immediate load of http://www.google.com/#5555 interrupts the load and starts loading http://www.google.com/#5555 which then proceeds to load.

Once http://www.google.com/#5555 is loaded, you then issue another load of http://www.google.com/ however this time the subsequent load of http://www.google.com/#5555 only does an anchor scroll (this is true whether the current page is http://www.google.com/ or http://www.google.com#5555) which does not interfere with the load of http://www.google.com/ which then completes.